# Copying files using memory map

Tags: c, linux, mmap, memcpy, bsd

I want to implement an effective file copying technique in C for my process which runs on BSD OS. As of now the functionality is implemented using read-write technique. I am trying to make it optimized by using memory map file copying technique.

Basically I will fork a process which mmaps both src and dst file and do memcpy() of the specified bytes from src to dst. The process exits after the memcpy() returns. Is msync() required here, because when I actually called msync with MS_SYNC flag, the function took lot of time to return. Same behavior is seen with MS_ASYNC flag as well?

i) So to summarize is it safe to avoid msync()?

ii) Is there any other better way of copying files in BSD. Because bsd seems to be does not support sendfile() or splice()? Any other equivalents?

iii) Is there any simple method for implementing our own zero-copy like technique for this requirement?

### My code

```
/* mmcopy.c

   Copy the contents of one file to another file, using memory mappings.

   Usage mmcopy source-file dest-file
*/
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *src, *dst;
    int fdSrc, fdDst;
    struct stat sb;

    if (argc != 3)
        usageErr("%s source-file dest-file\n", argv[0]);

    fdSrc = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fdSrc == -1)
        errExit("open");

    /* Use fstat() to obtain size of file: we use this to specify the
       size of the two mappings */

    if (fstat(fdSrc, &sb) == -1)
        errExit("fstat");

    /* Handle zero-length file specially, since specifying a size of
       zero to mmap() will fail with the error EINVAL */

    if (sb.st_size == 0)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    src = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fdSrc, 0);
    if (src == MAP_FAILED)
        errExit("mmap");

    fdDst = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fdDst == -1)
        errExit("open");

    if (ftruncate(fdDst, sb.st_size) == -1)
        errExit("ftruncate");

    dst = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdDst, 0);
    if (dst == MAP_FAILED)
        errExit("mmap");

    memcpy(dst, src, sb.st_size);       /* Copy bytes between mappings */
    if (msync(dst, sb.st_size, MS_SYNC) == -1)
        errExit("msync");
    enter code here
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It is needed. If you don't perform an `msync(2)`. You have no guarantee your changes will have been flushed back to the fs by the time you `munmap(2)` the file.

Comment: Thanks, but msync() seems to be taking considerable time, is there a effective way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with BSD to provide an authoritative answer to that, sorry.

Comment: `msync` merely waits for data to be committed to disk (like `fsync`). If you don't care, you can skip it.

Comment: Is there any simple method for implementing our own zero-copy like technique for this requirement?

Comment: A glance at freebsd source code for /bin/cp (https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/cp/) shows that they do mmap(2) only for the source file, and only if the source is 8M or less in size, and then just use write(2) to emit the destination data. You're sure you can do better? Have you measured? Sometimes an exec of a well-established system utility blends portability and performance nicely.

Comment: My approach is to mmap both the files and do a memcpy() followed by msync(). But my doubt is, is it safe to rely on msync() for deterministic  results?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `msync()` is not required.

When you do not specify `msync()`, the operating system flushes the memory-mapped pages in the background after the process has been terminated.  This is reliable on any POSIX-compliant operating system.

To answer the secondary questions:

Typically the method of copying a file on any POSIX-compliant operating system (such as BSD) is to use `open()` / `read()` / `write()` and a buffer of some size (16kb, 32kb, or 64kb, for example).  Read data into buffer from src, write data from buffer into dest.  Repeat until `read(src_fd)` returns 0 bytes (EOF).

However, depending on your goals, using mmap() to copy a file in this fashion is probably a perfectly viable solution, so long as the files being coped are relatively small (relative to the expected memory constraints of your target hardware and your application).  The mmap copy operation will require roughly 2x the total physical memory of the file. So if you're trying to copy a file that's a 8MB, your application will use 16MB to perform the copy.  If you expect to be working with even larger files then that duplication could become very costly.

So does using `mmap()` have other advantages?  Actually, no.

1. The OS will often be much slower about flushing mmap pages than writing data directly to a file using `write()`.  This is because the OS will intentionally prioritize other things ahead of page flushes so to keep the system 'responsive' for foreground tasks/apps.
2. During the time the mmap pages are being flushed to disk (in the background), the chance of sudden loss of power to the system will cause loss of data.  Of course this can happen when using `write()` as well but if `write()` finishes faster then there's less chance for unexpected interruption.
3. the long delay you observe when calling `msync()` is roughly the time it takes the OS to flush your copied file to disk.  When you don't call msync() it happens in the background instead (and also takes even longer for that reason).